# how to connect checkbox to if command

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
 class checkbox extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<checkbox> createState() => _checkboxState();
}

class _checkboxState extends State<checkbox> {
  bool? isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Checkbox(value:isChecked ,activeColor: Colors.red,shape: CircleBorder(), onChanged: (newbool) {
      setState(() {
        isChecked = newbool;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This is my checkbox code.

```
class thridcontrol extends GetxController {
  var isChecked = {}.obs;
  var spice = [];
  void editproduct(checkbox()) {
    if (!check.containskey(isChecked)) {
      spice.add("spicy");
  }
  get check => isChecked;
}
```

When i try out this code it just does not feel the if command as if it does not exist i've tried multiple things but nothing seems to work.

I basically want it so that if the checkbox is checked on item is added to the spice list "spicy" but my code is not working for that. When i try to print it in the terminal the list just comes out empty.

Comment: try: if (check.containskey(isChecked)) ....

Comment: no that did not work unfortunately but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

thridcontrol.dart

```
class thridcontrol extends GetxController {
  var isChecked = false.obs;
  var spice = [];

  void editproduct() {
    if (isChecked.value) {
      spice.add("spicy");

      debugPrint("-----------$spice");
    }
  }
}
```

checkboxDemo.dart

```
class CheckboxDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckboxDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckboxDemo> createState() => _CheckboxDemoState();
}

class _CheckboxDemoState extends State<CheckboxDemo> {
  bool? isChecked = false;

  final thridcontrol controller = Get.put(thridcontrol());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          // title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
      body: Center(
        child: Obx(() => Checkbox(
              value: controller.isChecked.value,
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                controller.isChecked.value = newValue!;
                controller
                    .editproduct(); // Call the method to update the 'spice' list
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```